# Is it necessary to decode html entities from form input field?

Tags: php, forms, html-entities, html-encode

I have a form that contains html entities in an input field, something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php htmlspecialchars($foo) ?>" />
```

If `$foo` takes in the *value* of something like "`<b>foo</b>`", it seems that when the form is posted to the PHP script, the value of `$_POST['foo']` is already decoded...so does that mean I don't need to use `htmlspecialchars_decode` to convert `$_POST['foo']` back to its original form `$foo`?

Thanks for any inputs on this issue.

Comment: Depends, if `$foo` is suddenly `" onclick="maliciuos code"` you have a problem, that's why you encode to entities, to avoid XSS.

Comment: @adeneo, thank you for your comment. Yes, that's true but I was actually referring to the need of decoding the code back to its original form after the encoded input (to avoid XSS) is posted to the php script

Comment: Is it actually returning the unencoded characters "<" and ">" or is it returning "&lt;" and "&gt;"? If the former, you won't see the HTML tags when printed to the page. If the latter, you will see the tags but when viewing the source of the page you will see the encoded characters.

Comment: it's returning "<" and ">" inside the php script that receives the submit...without any decoding involved

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to user input, code very defensively. Never make any assumptions. While the initial state may be set by the server, there's nothing stopping someone from manipulating the value of your hidden input to a malicious value. At that point it's on you to handle that value responsibly, so make sure you cover any case that is possible.

Comment: thanks david for your input, which i completely agree with. however, i was actually asking about decoding the encoded input when the form is submitted to the php script

Comment: Ah, I understand now! I could see a case where you still may want to decode. What if the value of $foo came through as

`&lt;b&gt;foo&lt;/b&gt;`?

Comment: ya, for some reason php's $_POST variable seems to have automatically decoded the encoded string...not sure if it's my server setting or if that apples to everyone else's

Comment: It's common. It's actually the browser that's doing the decoding up front. If you echo a value that has been run through htmlspecialchars two times though, it will output in the browser encoded - which means the post will be as well.